# Intuitive problem with multiple imputation

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I've read a lot of about multiple imputation and I think the explanation of that method on internet is no so comprehensive. I have some doubts about it and I will be pleased if you can help me with that.

Let's take code following :

```
 library(missForest)
 library(mic)
 #taking iris data 
 data <- iris
 #Randomly pick values for NA
 iris.mis <- prodNA(iris, noNA = 0.1) 
 #Turning on multiple imputation
 imputed_Data <- mice(iris.mis, m=5, maxit = 50, method = 'pmm', seed = 500)
```

where :

m - the number of imputations made per missing observation (5 is normal–generates 5 data sets with imputed/original values)

maxit -  the number of iterations

method - We use probable means

seed - Values to randomly generate from

As far as I understand  method = 'pmm' average the results,
but I'm not able to understand what exactly is happening when running that function. Can you please explain to me algorithm we are dealing with ? what exactly m and maxit are responsible for ?

Comment: PMM means predictive mean matching, consider this reading: https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-pmm.html

Answer (score 0):

As jay.sf pointed out PMM is predictive mean matching, it is an algorithm that tries to predict a "likely mean value" for the imputed metric based on the existing data in other columns. This is similar to other advanced imputation methods which do not simply take one constant value for each imputation (e.g. like mean imputation). This results in a different imputation value per case and has some inherent randomness/error.

To improve on that error and reduce variance the imputation isn't done just "one time" but multiple times.

`m` means the amount of imputed variants that are produced. E.g. with an `m = 5` you will get five imputed data sets with slight variations in their imputations.

`maxit` is the maximum of iterations the algorithm is able to learn and improve, similar to the epochs/iterations in a ML model.